# What is stage dot canvas?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, stage

I cannot understand the logic/structure/meaning ///  That is, I cannot pícture in my mind what   `stage.canvas`  stands for!
I have searched stackoverflow for questions involving `stage.canvas`, but they are about it. They do not explain what it means.
I have also gone to the API documentation > > no way!

I have learnt already one has to define a canvas in the html file
I have also learnt how to reference it from an external .js file
I have already learnt how to draw circles and animate them in the canvas
I know about objects; something about prototypes...

I'm wondering if  stage.canvas is valid whether I'm programming with say NetBeans or within Adobe Animate.
I t took me a loong while to "migrate" some physics examples from NetBeans to Adobe Animate. Would someone agree Adobe does a poor job in terms helping beginners?
I'm seeking a minimal example -- I believe five or six lines of code accompanied by an explanation would solve the conundrum -- or tell me **where to find info by myself**.

This is from github

```
 function init() {
            // get a reference to the canvas we'll be working with:
            var canvas = document.getElementById("testCanvas");
            // create a stage object to work with the canvas.
            // this is the top level node in the display list:
            var stage = new createjs.Stage(canvas);
```

This is clear and understandable to me. But from this, how come one can write stage.canvas   and what does it mean?

Thanks indeed for any kind help!

Comment: Hello. I've edited out the excess non technical language. We prefer the shortest questions possible to explain the issue. Also, as you've somewhat acknowledged in your question, this question might not be on topic for StackOverflow. StackOverflow is for debugging, not for more general learning. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

`new createjs.Stage(canvas)` isn't part of native JavaScript. This comes from the CreateJS library. According to [their documentation](https://createjs.com/getting-started), this appears to be that library's version of the canvas element.

You can look into it more via the link above, but if you're just learning JavaScript I would stick to using it without any libraries. If you want to create a canvas in native JavaScript, try using a [canvas element in HTML](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_canvas.asp).

Comment: To add to this, `stage.canvas` returns the canvas instance that the CreateJS Stage references. If you just have a reference to the stage, then you can look up the canvas it controls easily.  https://createjs.com/docs/easeljs/classes/Stage.html#property_canvas